# how to code MyClass<Integer>

Tags: java

Below I have 2 classes. The class 'ran' is the main class which will call the 'MyClass' class.

Question: How can I change 'MyClass' so that I can make it work with `MyClass<Integer>`?

Error: in ran class because I am using `<Integer>`.

```
public class ran {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass<Integer> m = new MyClass<Integer>();

    }
}


public class MyClass{
    public MyClass(int n){}
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing the type parameter `Integer` to a class that doesn't have any type parameters?

Comment: MyClass is not correct. I am not sure how can I code MyClass so that it takes <Integer>

Comment: Why do you need MyClass ? Yo cant use Integer m = new Integer()?

Comment: its just for learning purposes. I want to create my own ArraList<Integer> or LinkList<Integer>

Answer (score 0):

the following is a simple usage of generics. T is a template class for which we can use Integer, Float etc.

```
public class SOJavaApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {           
       MyClass<Integer> m = new MyClass<Integer>(5);
       m.printScreen();
   }
}

//T is the generic type
public class MyClass<T> {
    T value;     //attribute of type T

    public MyClass(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void printScreen() {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public void add(T n) {
       value += n;
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks this helps alot. just one question,  how to use add method on MyClass ex: m.add(19), m.add(20). Bc i am want to learn how the multi values store in LinkList with out losing the it. Any idea how to get started with that? again thanks ku

Comment: use T instead of the usual data type; i added a method for illustation

Comment: o i am sorry when I said add method, I mean like a array to store. ex: add(10), add(20), add(30). this will look like [10, 20, 30] not 60

Comment: you may want to use an ArrayList<T> then. Actually that request should warrant a new question right?